# Add a class name to an existing tag and fire event on that

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

i have an anchor tag as follows

```
<a href="#divEditPrivilegeLevelForFile" id="filePrivilege" class="inline UpdateLink" title="Edit File Privilege Level" data-fileid="@item.FileId">[ &Delta; ]</a>
```

i have a list of files which are getting bound to this tag.

I want to fire an event to at this anchor tag but i cannot use the id because the id would repeat itself.

So i have to use the class name
but it doesnot work with the class name as it contains spaces in between.

How can i do that?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "I want to fire an event to at this anchor tag but i cannot use the id because the id would repeat itself."
Just make sure you don't have multiple elements with the same ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQuery you just select it by that class, it handles checking for spaces/etc on it's own...

```
$('.UpdateLink').on( // your event etc
```

If you need it to have both classes in there you can just do:

```
$('.inline.UpdateLink')
```

Answer (score 0):

To select the elements with 2 classes at the same time use:

```
$(".inline.UpdateLink").doSomething();
```

Like in css.